# Why is "this" from superclass calling method from subclass?

Tags: java

I'm running over this problem while working with the following inheritance and JDK 14

```
interface A {

    default void a() {
        System.out.println("default a");
    }

    default void b() {
        System.out.println("default b");
    }
    
}

class AImp implements A {

    @Override
    public void a() {
        System.out.println("a from AImp");
    }

    @Override
    public void b() {
        System.out.println("b from AImp");
        this.a();
    }

}

class B extends AImp {

    @Override
    public void a() {
        System.out.println("a from B");
    }

    @Override
    public void b() {
        System.out.println("b from B");
        super.b();
    }

}
```

when I run

```
B b = new B();
    
b.b();
```

console gives

```
b from B
b from AImp
a from B
```

How come the keyword `this` in the `AImp` is referencing the instance of class B?
Am I being confused with something here?
Thank you for spending time.

Comment: What is the output you were expecting? Why wouldn't this called on an Object you initialize with `new B()` refer to an Object of type `B`?

Comment: There's only one object, of class B. So `this` always refers to an instance of class B.

Comment: Ah. I get it now. thank you guys so much.

Comment: I think there is only one instance and no matter how long inheritance chain is. That's why a call to ```this.a``` invokes ```a``` method from class ```B```.  The only way I know how you can call base class methods is ```super```.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have created an instance of `B`, it is it's dynamic type and due to *dynamic binding* always the method declared in B is called, because it overrides from A.

It does **not** matter from *where* you call the method, but it matters, what is the dynamic type.

With `super.method()` it is different, it explicitly goes up in the inheritance.

Note: constructors are not overriden, ever. So calling `this(params)` will not delegate to subclass.